# Cannot figure out why the link is not being found in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am sending a request

```
$http.get('/loadpage?category='+$scope.selectedCategory+'&page='+$scope.selectedPage).then(function(response){

    }).catch(function(){
        console.log("Error caught!");
    });
```

On my router.js file,

I have

```
router.get('/loadpage?category=xx&page=yy', function(req, res) {

res.send("Is this working");
});
```

I am not sure why my server is showing the following error.

angular.js:12587 GET http://localhost:3000/loadpage?category=1&page=1 404 (Not Found)

Because I tried sending a request to another url

```
router.get('/runthis/category=:xx',function(req, res){
var p = req.params.xx;

res.send(p);
});
```

by

```
function runthis (){
    $http.get('runthis/category=smackthat').then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log("Error caught!");
    });
}
```

And it works perfectly.

Can anyone help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're operating on a query string (the `?foo=bar` parts of urls) in express the query string gets parsed into req.query eg `req.query.foo === 'bar'` so the route should be just `/loadpage` and you should get data from req.query

Comment: So how do I take out the data?
It should be 
router.get('/loadpage', function(req, res){
var xx = req.query.category?
});

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your url a bit simpler such as :

```
router.get('/loadpage/:category/:page', function(req, res) {
   res.send("Is this working");
});
```

Makes your url parameters more semantic. and call it as :

```
$http.get('/loadpage/'+$scope.selectedCategory+'/'+$scope.selectedPage).then(function(response){

}).catch(function(){
    console.log("Error caught!");
});
```

Also, when you defined your url without `:` in `router.get('/loadpage?category=xx&page=yy'...` The router is looking for an exact match for the called url, in your case, you are passing variables and unless those 2 have `xx` and `yy` in them respectively, it's working as expected and throwing 404